# ASP.NET MVC is an Agile technology?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, agile

Do you think that ASP.NET MVC is an Agile technology? Which features make it Agile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Agile* programming is more of an approach or a philosophy toward programming rather than a mechanism or a framework. It refers to the way the team works together and how the project is run more than it does to the actual code being written.

Agile programming **is possible** using ASP.NET MVC, but it's also quite possible to do "traditional" bureaucratic development with ASP.NET MVC as well.

Agile programming is possible with nearly any framework, language, or platform.

Answer (score 4):

Agile is a method of development, not a technology.

If you mean, "Is ASP.NET MVC conducive to Agile development", and you define Agile as high testability and frequent iterative releases then yes, there are plenty of examples of testing frameworks and dependency injection/object mocking approaches to using ASP.NET MVC, and the Areas/Controllers/Actions approach allows for a heavily modularised and thus easily incrementally deployed solution.

[Stephen Walther's blog](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/default.aspx) is a great starting point for these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Test Driven Development is an [Agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) practice and ASP.NET MVC makes it easier to do this kind of development in contrast to WebForms for example. But I wouldn't say that ASP.NET MVC is agile. It is a pattern for developing applications.

Comment: what about webforms with proper separation of concerns?

Comment: @John Saunders: an interesting one on that part would be http://webformsmvp.com/.

Comment: @John, I only said that with ASP.NET MVC it is easier than WebForms. This doesn't mean that with proper separation of concerns you cannot do it in WebForms. It's just that by default WebForms doesn't advocate proper separation, while in ASP.NET MVC it is by design. But I totally agree with you.